# iOS 5 Multipart HTTP Stream Missing Headers

Tags: ios, ios5, http-headers

I am getting an MJPEG stream via a HTTP multipart/x-mixed-replace response. After each boundary there are an additional set of headers that have Content-Type, Content-Length, and a custom X-Date for recorded video.

In iOS 6, I can use a NSURLHttpResponse just fine and get all the headers I need to pull up the date and length of these images, but in iOS 5 it seems to be missing these last two headers I mentioned. I verified in Wireshark that the server is sending these headers to both the iOS 6 and 5 devices / simulators. However only the iOS 5 devices are not noticing them or something. I am wondering if this is not officially supported or if there has to be something more in depth done to access them.